# How to define a Range in excel say like Range("B &i : C" & j)

Tags: excel, range, vba

There is one table in my excel spreadsheet.

So I want to start the other table from a defined range below it.

Please help me to set a range like

```
Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B &i : C" & j)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.Sheets(1).Range("B" & i & ":C" & j)
```

Anything between `"` will be treated as strings.

Also if you are doing this from VBA Excel then it is no point in writing `Excel.Application`. It is understood by default.

Also if you want the range from the workbook from where the code is run then you don't need `Activeworkbook` You can use `ThisWorkbook` Reason being It's not necessary that both will be same at all times.

```
Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & i & ":C" & j)
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot Siddharth... It did work for me...
Yes, I changed your suggestions of Activeworkbook to ThisWorkbook